# Type mismatch in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, date, type-mismatch

In Excel 2010 works everything fine, but in Excel 2013 the error "Type mismatch" occurs. The problem is with the following codelines (different variants I have tried).

```
startDate = startDateCell.Value
startDate = CDate(startDateCell.Value)
startDate = CDate(Format(startDateCell.Value, "short date"))
```

The content of startDateCell is f.e. a string like "12.06.2016"

startDate is a Date-variable

Comment: Have you tried `DATEVALUE()`?

Comment: It sounds like your regional settings on the machine with 2013 do not recognise dates with a full stop delimiter.

Comment: The regional setting on the machine are set to EU and the date is in the EU format.

Comment: DATEVALUE() doesn't help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a US format date?  I assume not based on the time you're posting.  The problem may be that vba recognises it as a us date and interprete 13/1/2016 as 1/13/2016 (using British logic), referencing a 13th month, which gives an error.

```
Function Convertings() As String
  Convertings = Format(DateValue("13/1/2016"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Function
```

Comment: That's my point, I think it needs to be in US format, so it's currently in the sheet as ddmmyyyy, vba looks at it and interprets it as mmddyyyy as it's American.   You could check this with datepart if you can get any values to work at all?